# How to install Amazon Corretto on Manjaro?

Tags: manjaro, pacman, jdk, aur

I'm trying to install Amazon Corretto on Manjaro Linux. As it's available on AUR, I installed it using Yay.
However, whenever running any command, it's not found.

[image]

[image]

How do I properly set it?

Comment: You could check the installed files: `pacman -Ql amazon-corretto-11`

Comment: @rudib thanks... post updated. all the files are there

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed. All I had to run is the following command.

```
sudo archlinux-java fix
```

[Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Switching_between_JVM)

[image]

Comment: Nice! What I was going to do is look for `*/bin/java` and create a symlink or add it to `PATH`, but it looks like `archlinux-java fix` does that for you. But please use text formatted as `code` when including terminal output (instead of screenshots). It makes it easier to read and especially copy.